# Using wfs-t in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3, web-feature-service

I'm using [OpenLayers-3.6.0](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/) in a web application. I have **wfs** layer as follow:

```
var url="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?&" + 
      "service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=usa:states";
var format = new ol.format.WFS({});
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'proxy.cgi?url='+ encodeURIComponent(url),
    format: format
});
layer wfs = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'states',
    source: source
});
```

I edit this Point layer as follow:

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Point'
});
```

Now I want to save this layer in server side. In [OpenLayers-2](http://openlayers.org/two/) we defined a saveStrategy and then call save method of it. It is shown as follows:

```
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

/*
* change layer's features
*/

saveStratefy.save();
```

**How can I do it in [OpenLayers-3.6.0](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/)**?

Answer (score 1):

This is now up to the application code to handle. The Boundless SDK has some code for this.
See: http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/06/openlayers-editing-wfs-t/ and also the code in this repository: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/sdk/src/main/resources/client/ol3-common/app/TransactionHandler.js